# ant command needs sudo authority to run on OSX?

Tags: macos, ant, sudo, environment, authority

I just installed Apache Ant.

I unzipped file and put in to my `~/` folder.

And I edited my `.bash_profile` like below (of course, I did `source`, too)

```
export AKKA_HOME=/usr/local/share/akka
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/share/scala
export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/ImageMagick
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MAGICK_HOME/lib/
export ANT_HOME=/Users/juneyoungoh/apache-ant-1.9.5

# PostgreSQL.app
# export POSTGRESQL_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/
# pg_dir=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib

export POSTGRESQL_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin
export PGDATA=/Users/juneyoungoh/Documents/postgreSQL
```

After this, I type `ant -v` commend and got an error like...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

So I tried `sudo ant -v` and it works. I do not know why `ant` command needs sudo authority and how to do it without the authority.

Thanks for answers :D (I want to know reason and solution both! ty)